# AngularJS with RequireJS tags showing breifly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am bringing angularjs in using require but the problem is, the angular tags show for a moment until the angular script is parsed.

Do I have to bring angularjs out of requirejs and have it defined before requirejs is initialized or is there a better way to do it?

Here is my requirejs:

```
require.config({
    map: {},
    paths: {
        "angular": [
            "angular"
        ],
        "jquery": [
            "jquery"
        ],
        'bootstrap': [
            'bootstrap'
        ],
        'kendo': [
            'kendo'
        ]
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
        'kendo': ['jquery'],
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading angular outside of the head of the document (as you are doing by using requirejs to load angular), ng-cloak will not work immediately since the required styles to hide angular elements are contained in angular.js.

To fix, you can manually add these styles yourself in the head of the document.  A simple style tag will do it.

```
<style type="text/css">
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

As a catch all, you can add the ng-cloak directive to the body tag of the document (or the same tag that has ng-app), although best practice is to add ng-cloak only to elements that require it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the use case that [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is designed to address.

> **The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.**
>
> The directive can be applied to the  element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple `ngCloak` directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

Comment: Actually it´s even enough to add ng-cloak to the body element like: <body ng-cloak>